# Error while setting column equal to another pandas ( ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I have the following dataframe in pandas

```
        datadate  fyear  ebit  glp  ibc  ...  ind  status    year  month  a_date
gvkey                                    ...                                    
7767    20130831    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    0       1  2013.0    8.0       0
10871   20110930    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    0       1  2011.0    9.0       0
15481   20110930    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    0       1  2011.0    9.0       0
15582   19821031    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    1       1  1982.0   10.0       0
15582   19831031    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    1       1  1983.0   10.0       0
         ...    ...   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...     ...     ...    ...     ...
282553  20071231    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    0       1  2007.0   12.0       0
282553  20081231    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    0       1  2008.0   12.0       0
282553  20091231    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    0       1  2009.0   12.0       0
294911  20150930    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    0       1  2015.0    9.0       0
321467  20161231    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  ...    0       1  2016.0   12.0       0
```

I want to run the following command to assign the `year` value to the column `a_date` if `month` is at least 6. (Please do not consider that there are NaNs in the dataframe):

```
df.iloc[(df['month']>=6).values,-1]=df.iloc[(df['month']>=6).values,-3]
```

but I get the error

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

How do I proceed then? I really cannot get why I get this error. I googled and found some solutions to the same ValueError but they do not apply to my case. I would like to avoid using dictionaries and keep everything in one line if possible. I know I could solve with a loop but I am looking for a more efficient solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the error comes from the iloc function in the right part of your line (after =), because this function returns a series and not a value. So you are affecting a serie to a dataframe cell, which for me is the source of the error. Using pandas, for me the code would be :

```
df.loc[df['month'] >= 6, 'a_date'] = df['year']
```

The `loc` function allows to select a group of lines according to a condition (here `df['month'] >= 6`), a column to apply a change (here `'a_date'`) and the change you want to apply (here, as it is another column of the dataframe : `df['year']`)

Answer (score 0):

I found an efficient solution myself using `np.where`:

```
df['a_date']=np.where(df['month']>=6,df['year'],df['year']-1)
```